# cannot insert dropdownlist value to database in mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, database, controller

I have a RegisterViewModel which takes the input from a user and store it in database. I have used an IEnumerable for storing the roles in dropdownlist.The view works fine but i am unable to get the dropdownlist value and store it into user table. What should i do to get the dropdownlist value?

```
public class RegisterViewModel
    {
        [Required]
        [DisplayName("User Name")]
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Remote("EmailAlreadyExists", "Validation", ErrorMessage = "User with this mail exists")]
        [DisplayName("Email")]
        public string Email { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [DisplayName("Password")]
        public string Password { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [DisplayName("Confirm Password")]
        public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Roles { get; set; }
    }
```

My Role Model

```
public class Role
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string  Name { get; set; }
}
```

View for Roles is,

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Roles, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Roles, Model.Roles, "Select Roles" , new {id = "Roles" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Roles, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

And finally my controller

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    RegisterViewModel uvm = new RegisterViewModel();
    uvm.Roles = from r in roles
    select new System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem
    {
        Text = r.Name,
        Value = r.Id.ToString()
    };
    return View(uvm);                 
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Index(RegisterViewModel register)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        string code = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

        userRepo.Insert(new Models.User()
        {
            UserName = register.UserName,
            Email = register.Email,
            Password = register.Password,    
            /* Role = register.Roles */              
            CreatedDate = DateTime.Now,
            AuthCode = code,
            Status = false
        });  
        SendMail(register.UserName, register.Email, code);
        return RedirectToAction("Thankyou");
    } 
    return View(register);
}
```

Comment: You cannot bind a `<select>` to a collection of complex objects - it posts back a single value. You need a property to bind the selected value to (say `public int SelectedRole { get; set; }`) and then its `@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedRole, Model.Roles, "Select Roles" )`

Comment: try to Role = register.Roles.Value

Comment: @Ravikumar, That would just throw a `NullReferenceException` since `Roles` is `null`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add new property in RegisterViewModel

```
 public class RegisterViewModel
 { 
   [Required]
                                    [DisplayName("User Name")]
                                    public string UserName { get; set; }
                                    [Required]
                                    [Remote("EmailAlreadyExists", "Validation", ErrorMessage = "User with this mail exists")]
                                    [DisplayName("Email")]
                                    public string Email { get; set; }
                                    [Required]
                                    [DisplayName("Password")]
                                    public string Password { get; set; }
                                    [Required]
                                    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
                                    [DisplayName("Confirm Password")]
                                    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
                                    [Required]
                                    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Roles { get; set; }
   **public string SelectedRole {get;set;}**
 }
```

and dropdown sould be like bewlo

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedRole , Model.Roles, "Select Roles" , new {id = "Roles" })
```

You controller action look like

```
[HttpPost]
                            [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
                            public ActionResult Index(RegisterViewModel register)
                            {
                                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                                {
                                    string code = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

                                    userRepo.Insert(new Models.User()
                                    {
                                        UserName = register.UserName,
                                        Email = register.Email,
                                        Password = register.Password,    
                                        Role = register.SelectedRole
                                        CreatedDate = DateTime.Now,
                                        AuthCode = code,
                                        Status = false
                                    });  
                                    SendMail(register.UserName, register.Email, code);
                                    return RedirectToAction("Thankyou");
                                } 
                                return View(register);
                            }
```